# Flexera agent installation getting timed out

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation, runbook

Hi I am trying to install custom extension via a azure automation runbook in Windows Azure VM but cmdlet `Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension` is getting timed out, any suggestion what could be going wrong here?

Error message:

> Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'Provisioning of VM extension 'FlexeraInstall' has timed out. Extension installation may be taking too long, or extension status could not be.

Comment: Does the command work locally(windows powershell)?

Comment: No even if I try locally by connecting powershell session to azure then also it fails with same error. Also forget to mentioned that VM is inside an azure DTL lab. any networking setting could be blocking this?

Comment: In the DTL lab, seems you need to execute Azure VM custom script extension via `Artifacts`, refer to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devtestlab/2016/09/22/tips-and-tricks-on-azure-devtest-labs-artifacts-development-and-debugging/), as mentioned, `At very high-level, DevTest Labs artifacts is a thin wrapper to execute Azure VM custom script extension or any other Azure VM extensions, and enables an end-user friendly experience on top of it.`

Comment: Yes I have tried executing Azure VM custom script extension but it didn't work(though I tried directly not through artifacts) either. just for the simplicity I tried creating simple text file in C drive of the Azure VM by executing a powershell cmdlet in custom script but could not write anything and script executed successfully.